# selenium webdriver xpath search by index

Tags: java, xpath, indexing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify a xpath of a textfield where the class name is "DeleteBackwardTextField" and Origin class is "UITextField". There are no label, name and text it. No other information to identify it.
**There are 2 textfield with same above properties.** 
So my following xpath identifies two text fields.

```
By.xpath("//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField']")
```

How can I identify the xpath of 1 particular field. I assume index can be used. Can anybody provide a syntax for indexing. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you try this?By.xpath("//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField'][i]")

Means: All elements with tag name "textfield" having "class" attribute value as "DeleteBackwardTextField" in the document, that are the 'i'th child of their parent.

Comment: Tried it. It searches but fails to identify the object. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can go with XPATH or CSS. The trick is to have a list of WebElements identified and then you can iterate over it.

```
    List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(by.cssSelector(...); //or XPATH;
    for (WebElement txtField : myList) {
       // do what you need here, for each element at a time
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath.

`(//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField'])[index]`

EX: `(//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField'])[1]` -> first element when you have many elements matching `//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField']`

---

Note that this xpth - `//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField'][2]` has different meaning - it means second child of its parent.

Comment: Tried it. It searches but fails to identify the object. Thanks

Comment: index does not work - but this `//textfield[@class='DeleteBackwardTextField']` works?

Comment: Yes this works. It selects both the text field I have on screen. So I want to differentiate between these two. My function is to identify first text field then enter data and then move to next text field.